# Algorithm for Connect 4 Evaluation of Data Set

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a connect 4 AI, and saw many people were using [this](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Connect-4) data set, containing all the legal positions at 8 ply, and their eventual outcome.

I am using a standard minimax with alpha/beta pruning as my search algorithm. It seems like this data set could could be really useful for my AI. However, I'm trying to find the best way to implement it. I thought the best approach might be to process the list, and use the board state as a hash for the eventual result (win, loss, draw).

What is the best way for to design an AI to use a data set like this? Is my idea of hashing the board state, and using it in a traditional search algorithm (eg. minimax) on the right track? or is there is better way?

**Update**: I ended up converting the large move database to a plain test format, where 1 represented X and -1 O. Then I used a string of the board state, an an integer representing the eventual outcome, and put it in an `std::unsorted_map` (see [Stack Overflow With Unordered Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501257/stack-overflow-with-unordered-map) to for a problem I ran into). The performance of the map was excellent. It built quickly, and the lookups were fast. However, I never quite got the search right. Is the right way to approach the problem to just search the database when the number of turns in the game is less than 8, then switch over to a regular alpha-beta?

Comment: Not sure I am following, are you asking for a heuristic for a [min-max algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax)? Or is it something different?

Comment: @amit I already have a minimax with alpha/beta pruning and a hueristic. I thought that using this data set could be very helpful in my search, because it gives the known end conditions after 8 ply. I was planning on incorporating the data as a "known condition" in the search. I'm looking for higher level design feedback (aka. is this a good idea). Is there anything I should clarify in the question?

Comment: There are plenty literature about this topic, you can see - [this](http://www-personal.engin.umd.umich.edu/~shaout/connect4.pdf) - [this](http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~csc384h/fall/presentations/nov30/wu_paper.pdf) - or [this read](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/academics/courses/fall03/ai/handouts/assign4.pdf) page 5 where a Doctor gives several tips to his students

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your approach seems correct.**

For the first 8 moves, use alpha-beta algorithm, and use the look-up table to evaluate the value of each node at depth 8.

Once you have "exhausted" the table (exceeded 8 moves in the game) - you should switch to regular alpha-beta algorithm, that ends with terminal states (leaves in the game tree).

This is extremely helpful because:

Remember that the complexity of searching the tree is `O(B^d)` - where `B` is the branch factor (number of possible moves per state) and `d` is the needed depth until the end. 

By using this approach you effectively decrease both `B` and `d` for the maximal waiting times (longest moves needed to be calculated) because:

1. **Your maximal depth shrinks** significantly to `d-8` (only for the last moves), effectively decreasing `d`!
2. **The branch factor itself tends to shrink** in this game after a few moves (many moves become impossible or leading to defeat and should not be explored), this decreases `B`.
3. In the first move, you shrink the number of developed nodes as well
   to `B^8` instead of `B^d`.

So, because of these - the maximal waiting time decreases significantly by using this approach.

---

Also note: If you find the optimization not enough - you can always expand your look up table (to 9,10,... first moves), of course it will increase the needed space exponentially - this is a tradeoff you need to examine and chose what best serves your needs (maybe even store the entire game in file system if the main memory is not enough should be considered)

Comment: Quick clarification: When I am searching the look-up table, I should be using an alpha-beta search with the limits set to the key value for a win/loss so I can break out early, correct? Also, if the data set doesn't include "forced" moves, it would probably be more efficient to do a search at a depth of 1 before searching the data, correct? Thank you for the clear explanation.

Comment: @Kyryx: Not sure I follow the question, when you use the look up table you do it instead of alpha beta (or to be exact, with alpha-beta up to depth 1, and use the win/loss/draw value to conclude how to continue). Regarding the second question - what do you mean by 'if the data set doesn't include "forced" moves, it would probably be more efficient to do a search at a depth of 1 before searching the data, correct?' a search of depth 1 and searching in the look up table are equivalent - both are extremely quick.

Comment: The data set only lists the legal positions and their outcomes _at_ 8 ply. So, for example, if I am making the first move of the game, and search the look up table, it would return nothing. So, for the first move, wouldn't I need to do some sort of search, such as alpha-beta, up to a depth of 8 for the data set to be applicable?

Comment: @Kyryx: Og, I thought it is up to 8. So basically - yes, you need to do alpha-beta up to 8 in the first turns - and use the look up table to determine the "value" each node at depth 8 (rather then expanding this nodes to leaves). Once you reach turn 9, do alpha-beta until the end. I'll edit the answer to indicate it as well.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question to try and make the language clearer too