# Stack Overflow With Unordered Map

Tags: c++, stl, stack-overflow

For a project, I have an opening table that I decided to put in a `std::unordered_map`. Unfortunately, I am restricted to hard-coding the entire map. So, I decided to split the initialization into multiple files.

```
class OpeningBook
{
public:
    OpeningBook();
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> opening_database_;
    void init1();
    void init2();
    void init3();
    void init4();
    void init5();
};
```

and the constructor just calls the `init` functions:

```
OpeningBook::OpeningBook()
{
    init1();
    init2();
    init3();
    init4();
    init5();
}
```

All of which just look like this:

```
void OpeningBook::init1()
{
    opening_database_.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("0001000000-10000001000000-1000001100000-1-1000",5000));
    opening_database_.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("0001000000-10000001000000-1000000100000-1-1100",5000));
    opening_database_.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("0001000000-10000001000000-1000000100001-1-1000",5000));
    opening_database_.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("0001000000-10000001000000-1000000100000-1-1010",5000));
    opening_database_.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("0001000000-10000001000000-1000000100010-1-1000",5000));
    opening_database_.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("0001000000-10000001000000-1000000100000-1-1001",5000));
    opening_database_.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("0001000000-10000001000000-100000010000-11-1000",0));
    opening_database_.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("0001000000-10000001000000-100000010000-10-1100",5000));
    // continues
}
```

However, as soon as my code hits the opening brace in `init1()`, it throws a stack overflow exception. I thought that a stack overflow couldn't occur because an `unordered_map` is on the heap. What's going on? and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Refactor the code to read the key/value pairs each on a line in a file. Then you can read the file line-by-line and call opening_database_.insert() in a loop instead of generating a giant wall of code.

Comment: @Tergiver Like I said in the question, I am not able to do so. That was how I wanted to do it too. However, system restrictions make any sort of file IO impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How many items are you inserting in each `initx()` method? If it's many thousands, then it's possible that the compiler is generating code that uses a large number of temporaries on the stack, and simply asks for more stack space than there is available.

Try splitting your initialisation methods up further and see if that solves the problem.

A better approach might be to have a table which contains the initialisation data:

```
static const struct {
    const char *str;
    int n;
} DatabaseInitData[] = {
    {"0001000000-10000001000000-1000001100000-1-1000",5000},
    {"0001000000-10000001000000-1000000100000-1-1100",5000},
    {"0001000000-10000001000000-1000000100001-1-1000",5000},
    // etc
};
```

Then, in your constructor:

```
OpeningBook::OpeningBook()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(DatabaseInitData)/sizeof(DatabaseInitData[0]); i++) {
        opening_database_.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>(
            DatabaseInitData[i].str,
            DatabaseInitData[i].n));
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now, it is about 20,000 entries per `initx()`. Do you have any idea what the right number might be per `init`, if I do decide to break it down? A table is certainly an interesting idea, I'll see if I can give that a try. Thank you

Comment: It is possible that your compiler has sufficient C++11 support for this to work: make `DatabaseInitData` an array of `std::pair<string,int>`, use `{}` initializers for it, and then change `OpeningBook::OpeningBook` to `for( auto& elem:DatabaseInitData ) { opening_database_.insert( std::move(elem) ); }`.  Which I think is pretty neat.

Comment: @Kyryx: The "right" number is difficult to predict since it depends on so many different factors. You would have to experiment to find a number that works for your compiler and platform. However, the table approach is much more preferable.